# Apache cordova plugins for tracking data activities

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, apache-cordova

I am looking for an apache cordova plugin which can provide the details of "use mobile data for" statistics in IOS . In IOS, in settings you can see these details i.e. Setting->Mobile Data->use mobile data for.  Is there a plugin that does this?

Comment: Any help on this question? Please...

Comment: Here are all the plugins and I could not find one for iOS and statistics:  https://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?platforms=cordova-ios